# QTcpSocket pointer produces SIGSEGV in a view. (QT5)

Tags: c++, qt, pointers, qt5, segmentation-fault

Hi,

I've got a SIGSEGV when I want to use a QTcpSocket with the following code. (more explanation at the very bottom)

*Function to create a QTTCPSocket (which will keep the QTcpSocket pointer):*

```cpp
std::shared_ptr<QTTCPSocket> createQtSocket(std::string host, unsigned int port)
{
    QTcpSocket *sock = new QTcpSocket;
    sock->connectToHost(QHostAddress(QString::fromStdString(host)), port);
    if (!sock->waitForConnected())
        throw std::runtime_error("Connection refused");
    return std::make_shared<QTTCPSocket>(sock);
}
```

*QTTCPSocket class:*

```cpp
class QTTCPSocket {
public:
    QTTCPSocket(QTcpSocket *socket)
        : _socket(socket)
    {};

    ~QTTCPSocket() = default;

    void send(const std::string &msg)
    {
        std::cout << msg << std::endl;
        _socket->write(&msg[0], static_cast<qint64>(msg.length())); // produces a SIGSEGV if called from a qt event (a button for example)
        _socket->waitForBytesWritten(0);
    }

private:
    QTcpSocket *_socket;
};
```

*Main function:*

```cpp
int main()
{
    std::shared_ptr<QTTCPSocket> socket = createQtSocket("127.0.0.1", 33333);
    ViewStateMachine vsm(socket);
    vsm.init();
    vsm.start();
}
```

*ViewStateMachine class (hpp):*

```cpp
class ViewStateMachine {
public:
    ViewStateMachine(std::shared_ptr<QTTCPSocket> sock);
    void init();
    void start();
    std::shared_ptr<QTTCPSocket> getSock();
private:
    LoginView *_loginView;
    std::shared_ptr<QTTCPSocket> _sock;
};
```

*ViewStateMachine class (cpp):*

```cpp
#include "ViewStateMachine.hpp"

ViewStateMachine::ViewStateMachine(std::shared_ptr<QTTCPSocket> socket)
    : _sock(std::move(socket))
{
}

void ViewStateMachine::init()
{
    _loginView = new LoginView(this);
    _loginView->init();
}

void ViewStateMachine::start()
{
    _loginView->show();
}

std::shared_ptr<QTTCPSocket> ViewStateMachine::getSock()
{
    _sock->send("test1"); // SIGSEGV inside (check above) 
    return _sock; // if I remove _sock->send("test1"), it SIGSEGV in the shared_ptr's constructor (only if called from a qt event (a button for example)
}
```

LoginView is a passive class, which register an event with `QObject::connect(_connectBtn, SIGNAL(clicked()), this, SLOT(onClick_connectBtn()));` with `onClick_connectBtn()` a member function of `LoginView`.

All these pieces of code might be confused so here a step-by-step explanation:

1. Start in `main()`: create a `QTcpSocket *` contained in a `QTTCPSocket class` contained in a `std::shared_ptr<QTTCPSocket>`.
2. Create a `ViewStateMachine` instance with the `shared_ptr`, which will be stored in the instance. We will call it `vsm`.
3. Call `vsm.init()` which will create a `LoginView` instance with `this` (`vsm`). `LoginView` will store the `ViewStateMachine` instance.
4. Call `vsm.start()` which will call `_loginView.show()` (from QT's QWidget), it will show the login view.

Everything works well and we can see the login view.

However, if I want to use my socket in the LoginView :
 * when I want to use it from `_loginView->init()` or in the LoginView's constructor, it works well!
 * when I want to use it from `LoginView::onClick_connectBtn` (called by QT, perhaps in a special environment like a constructor, not sure), it produces a SIGSEGV where I commented above in the code (shared_ptr's constructor or write function from the QT' socket).

To get the socket from `LoginView`, I use `ViewStateMachine::getSock()` (`_viewStateMachine->getSock()`).

Valgrind shows

`pure virtual method called
terminate called without an active exception`

The shared_ptr's constructor produces a SIGSEGV when it uses its mutex to increment the value.
The write SIGSEGV when I use `_socket` (QT' socket). The pointer address didn't change from beginning to end.

If there's any other question, please ask!

Thanks a lot for helping :).

EDIT: It works if I replace every std::shared_ptr with a C pointer.

Comment: `createQtSocket` function looks very strange. You create a socket, connect it, then you create another one and return in? Why? First one socket is a memory and resource leak. Probably you wanted to write `shared_ptr` instead of `make_shared`?

Comment: Firstly I create a QTcpSocket with `new`, I connect it and then I create a new instance but QTTCPSocket this time and I send my QTcpSocket inside. A bit confusing sorry.
Is that correct to you?

Comment: Now it's clear. Very strange naming... Next - call of `waitForBytesWritten(0)` is useless. It should be not zero.

Comment: I think that your problem is in [thread affinity](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/thread-basics.html). You should call `_socket->write` from thread, where your `QTcpSocket` belongs. You may do in with `QueuedConnection` or `Qt::BlockingQueuedConnection` slot calls.

Comment: Yes, little mistake, it should be `waitForBytesWritten(-1)`, thanks.

Comment: I did some research but I still have a few questions:
1/ When I run my program with GDB it shows only one thread, and if I sleep in the "callback" (`onClick_connectBtn()`) it will freeze everything. Am I right? So it should work.
2/ Not sure how to add a `Qt::ConnectionType` like `Qt::BlockingQueuedConnection` to `connectToHost()`. Only way I see is to use `connect()` which take some unknown arguments to me. Is `connect()` the good way?

Comment: Then you should start with learning Qt basics. Read about signals/slots first. Then about threads.